# How to change the shortcut directories in Files?

Tags: ubuntu, file-manager

I'd like to redirect the documents, downloads, music, and videos that are on the sidebar of the files application to another location that is in another partition. So far my Internet research have only shown me solutions for older versions. The properties for those directories doesn't let me change the redirection as the instructions shown.

Comment: What OS do you use? A lot of core information is missing.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. I wrote it severl times but the edit seemd to drop it

Comment: Oh, i saw that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's easy. It can't be done, not without compiling from source. I would just move the directories and create symlinks instead from where the directories are to where you want them, something like this:

```
mv ~/Music /where/i/want/my/music
ln -s /where/i/want/my/music ~/Music
```